# Mongoose Error: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "....." (type string) at path "author" because of "BSONError"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, next.js

I'm encountering an error while working with Mongoose in my NextJS application. Specifically, I'm trying to save a document where one of the fields references an ObjectId, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Cast to ObjectId failed for value "....." (type string) at path "author" because of "BSONError"
```

Here's a bit of context:

- I have a Mongoose schema that includes a field named `author` which is supposed to be a reference to another document.
- When I try to save a new document, I pass the value for the `author` field as a string.

I understand that Mongoose is trying to cast this string to an ObjectId, but it's encountering an error in the process.

Here's a simplified version of my schema for reference:

```js
 author:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:"User",
        required: true,
    },
```

Here's the code for saving

```
export async function createText({ text, author, communityId, path }: Params) {
   
    try{

      connectToDB();
      const createdText= await Text.create({
          text,author,community:null,path
      });
      // Update User Model
      await User.findByIdAndUpdate(author,{
          $push:{text:createdText._id}
      })
      revalidatePath(path);
  } 
  catch (error:any){
    throw new Error(`Error creating thread:${error.message}`)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to save a new document, I pass the value for the author field as a string

You have to convert the **author** from `String` to `ObjectId` using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId()` method.

**NOTE:** The `String` value of **author** should be a valid `ObjectID`.

```
const createdText= await Text.create({
    text,
    author: (new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(author)),
    community: null,
    path
});
```

Comment: I am getting this error when I tried to convert it.
```
Value of type 'typeof ObjectId' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?
```

Comment: Milan, I updated the answer. You need to create an instance of `ObjectId`

Comment: Now it's showing 
```
Error creating thread: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
```
The argument that is the author is equal to user_2V3l0ExQvUAEhjDhxBa2vKrd4Dp

Comment: I already mentioned that the value should be a valid `ObjectId`. The value `user_2V3l0ExQvUAEhjDhxBa2vKrd4Dp` is not a valid object id.